# Can anyone explain this structure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have this code

```
#define MAX_DIM 3
struct kd_node_t
{
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};

struct kd_node_t wp[] = {
    {{2, 3}}, {{5, 4}}, {{9, 6}}, {{4, 7}}, {{8, 1}}, {{7, 2}}
};
```

I dont understand the structure declaration in this case.Please help me out

Comment: a `double` array of size `MAX_DIM` (3) and two self-referenced pointers (maybe kd-tree implementation)? Assuming this is a tree implementation, most-likely a pointer to a left and right node (which should have the same type as this struct since they are all nodes).

Comment: Yes i am seeing a kd tree code but it's very tough to understand it

Comment: I don't get why you have an array x[3]. I thought a kd-tree was `struct kd_node_t{ int axis; double value; struct kd_node_t *left, *right};`

Comment: I am seeing the code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using brace initialiation.

The array gives a comma separated list initializing each struct in the array (if an explicit size were given, remaining structs would be zero initialized, I believe).

Since they're all similar, just take the first one, `{{2,3}}`.

This has a single element, `{2,3}` which tells you how to initialize the `x` member. Since only two values are specified, the remainder will be zero initialized, giving `[2,3,0]`. Likewise, `left` and `right` are intialized to null pointers.

The rest of the structs in the array are initialized similarly.